# Real-time (30fps) image processing vb.net

Tags: vb.net, performance, image-processing, lockbits

I'm not looking for any code here!

My question is reasonably simple: could an average home computer feasibly run a 30 fps 1024x768 image processing alg using vb.net.

Some more details;
1. I'm not expecting a hard yes. I'm hoping that no one can give me a hard NO (eg. it's not possibly because of the memory required to... lockbits need at least 0.5s to... etc.)
2. I'm asking so I don't spend the next 3 or so weeks trying to make this if the idea is fundamentally flawed. 
3. The resolution and FPS requirements are for example purposes only, half or double the fps or resolution shouldn't effect the answer (as far as I can tell).
4. Any method of image processing is acceptable. The actual images won't be edited, but I will need to read in the RGB values (for use in a separate parallel algorithm).

Note to editors: I'm hoping this questions doesn't get a perfect answer since that means it is possible. However if there is a hard reason why it's not possible then this question *isn't* based on opinion. Just wanted to make that clear before the vote to close gets started! :D

Comment: Pure .NET? Maybe - depending on the nature of the image processing you are doing and your system. For anything resource intense, you would want to use Emgu CV / Open CV which is written in optimized c/c++.

Comment: *Any method of image processing is acceptable.* Like what? Counting the number of pixels above a certain threshold? Calculating derivatives? Finding edges? Find out what the image shows? These all are very different operations with very different run time. Just iterating the ~1M pixels takes far less than 1/30 s (about 2 ms on my machine for a simple array, even less if parallelized). The critical thing is memory representation, transfer, cache coherency, etc.

Comment: I agree with @NicoSchertler without actually knowing what are you trying to achieve with your processing is this unanswerable as some algorithms are done in milliseconds on average machines and others in hours on supercomputers. Not sure if VB is the right way thou never seen anything with high performance coded in it.

Comment: Just to clarify, what I'm asking is can vb be used to give me the RGB values (in an array or some similar format) of each pixel for use in processing on a different thread. The different thread processing isn't in question here... can VB.net produce the data fast enough?

Comment: As I mentioned in my example: Yes, it is possible.